# Spring 3.1 @Cacheable with ehcache doesn't work

Tags: spring, ehcache

My @Cacheable with Spring and ehcache doesn't work, no datas are put on the cache.
When the application calls the cacheable method getFolProfile, the database is always call rather than the cache.
Can you, please, say me what is wrong in my code.

My root-context.xml:

```
    <cache:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"/>   
    <bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" p:configLocation="classpath:/cache/ehcache.xml"  /> 
    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager" p:cacheManager-ref="ehcache"/>
```

My Service :

```
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    @Service
    public class FolManager {
@Autowired
FolDao folDao;



@Cacheable(value = "oneCache", key = "#email")
public FolProfileForm getFolProfile(String email) {
    return folDao.retrieveByLogin(email);
}
    }
```

My ehcache.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd">
    <diskStore path="c:/tmp" />
    <defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="10000" eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="120"
    timeToLiveSeconds="120" overflowToDisk="true" diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="30" maxElementsOnDisk="10000000"
    diskPersistent="false" diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />
    <cache name="oneCache" maxElementsInMemory="100000" maxElementsOnDisk="10000000" eternal="true" diskPersistent="true"
    overflowToDisk="true" diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" />
    </ehcache>
```

Thanks for your help
Michel

Comment: Can you please post the code showing where `FolManager` is a Spring-managed bean, injected into your Controller?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're defining caching in the service layer. At http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html, it is specifically noted as follows:

> Note
>
> `<cache:annotation-driven/>` only looks for @Cacheable/@CacheEvict on
>   beans in the same application context it is defined in. This means
>   that, if you put `<cache:annotation-driven/>` in a WebApplicationContext
>   for a DispatcherServlet, it only checks for @Cacheable/@CacheEvict
>   beans in your controllers, and not your services. See Section 16.2,
>   “The DispatcherServlet” for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
<cache:annotation-driven cache-manager="cacheManager"  />
```

You have to tell Spring where cache-manager is.

Comment: Hi Willy, Thanks to answer. I think it not necessary because it's the default name like my bean.

Comment: Sorry its my fault. How do call the method with `@Cacheable`?

Comment: Is the instance extended from this abstract controller managed by Spring?

Comment: Sorry, the cacheable method is called from a abstract controller which IS MANAGED by Spring.

 @ModelAttribute
 @RolesAllowed({"ROLE_ADMIN","ROLE_USER"})
 public void initFolInSessionBean(HttpServletRequest req, ModelMap model) {
    
   folProfileForm = folManager.getFolProfile(folInSessionBean.getLogin());

Answer (score 0):

When proxy-target-class attribute is set to true, class-based proxies are created. CGLIB will be used to create the proxy for a given target object. Make sur that you have CGLIB in your dependencies.

If you have the choice, prefer JDK dynamic proxies by setting proxy-target-class attribute to false and by implementing at least one interface on your class.

Comment: Hi Vincent, Thanks to take time to answer; yes I have cglib in my pom  <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>     , for my dao I use interface but not for the services

Comment: no exception, the database is called each time; when I launch tomcat I see the created file in c:/tmp but it always stays with 0 ko

Answer (score 0):

Please check your ehCache logs for exceptions like the following:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.RefreshableCacheEntry
```

You use disk persistent cache (diskPersistent=true), so you have to check that your FolProfileForm object is Serializable.
From the ehCache documentation:

> Only data that is Serializable can be placed in the DiskStore. Writes to and from the disk use ObjectInputStream and the Java serialization mechanism. Any non-serializable data overflowing to the disk store is removed and a NotSerializableException is thrown.

It could be the case that your data aren't placed to your cache (filesystem), so it tries to get it from the method invocation again and again.
You can use memory store cache where you can save even not serializable data.